# Why is my code causing "unchecked or unsafe operations" warning being flagged by compiler?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac, unsafe, unchecked

My java compiler is complaining that my code uses "unchecked or unsafe operations". Any idea which lines are causing that in the two code snippets?

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private final void prepareChannelAccountStringsParserImplementedClassConstructor() {
    try {
        String channelAccountStringsParserImplementedClassName = channelIdentifier + "AccountStringsParser";
        Class channelAccountStringsParserImplementedClass = Class.forName(channelAccountStringsParserImplementedClassName);
        Class[] channelAccountStringsParserImplementedClassArguments = new Class[1];
        channelAccountStringsParserImplementedClassArguments[0] = String.class;
        channelAccountStringsParserImplementedClassConstructor = channelAccountStringsParserImplementedClass.getConstructor(channelAccountStringsParserImplementedClassArguments);
        channelAccountStringsParserImplementedParseMethod = channelAccountStringsParserImplementedClass.getMethod("parse", String.class);
        channelAccountStringsParserGetRequestIDMethod = channelAccountStringsParserImplementedClass.getMethod("getRequestID");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
        NotifyMeListenersLogsDB notifyMeListenersLogsDB = DatabaseController.getInstance().getNotifyMeListenersLogsDB();
        notifyMeListenersLogsDB.writeDeveloperException(classNotFoundException);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException noSuchMethodException) {
        NotifyMeListenersLogsDB notifyMeListenersLogsDB = DatabaseController.getInstance().getNotifyMeListenersLogsDB();
        notifyMeListenersLogsDB.writeDeveloperException(noSuchMethodException);
    }
}

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public synchronized final void requestChannelAccountsCompletionSuccess(String responseContent) {
    Object channelAccountStringsParserImplementedInstance;
    ArrayList<ChannelAccount> channelAccounts = null;
    String requestID = null;
    try {
        channelAccountStringsParserImplementedInstance = channelAccountStringsParserImplementedClassConstructor.newInstance(responseContent);
        channelAccounts = (ArrayList<ChannelAccount>) channelAccountStringsParserImplementedParseMethod.invoke(channelAccountStringsParserImplementedInstance, responseContent);
        requestID = (String) channelAccountStringsParserGetRequestIDMethod.invoke(channelAccountStringsParserImplementedInstance);
    } catch (InstantiationException instantiationException) {
        NotifyMeListenersLogsDB notifyMeListenersLogsDB = DatabaseController.getInstance().getNotifyMeListenersLogsDB();
        notifyMeListenersLogsDB.writeDeveloperException(instantiationException);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException illegalAccessException) {
        NotifyMeListenersLogsDB notifyMeListenersLogsDB = DatabaseController.getInstance().getNotifyMeListenersLogsDB();
        notifyMeListenersLogsDB.writeDeveloperException(illegalAccessException);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException invocationTargetException) {
        NotifyMeListenersLogsDB notifyMeListenersLogsDB = DatabaseController.getInstance().getNotifyMeListenersLogsDB();
        notifyMeListenersLogsDB.writeDeveloperException(invocationTargetException);
    }
    channelAccountStringsParserImplementedInstance = null;
    try {
        startChannelConnections(channelAccounts);
        isStarted = true;
        LoadBalancer.getInstance().sendSuccessAcknowledgement(requestID);
    } catch (NotifyMeListenersApplicationInitializationException notifyMeListenersApplicationInitializationException) {
        NotifyMeListenersLogsDB notifyMeListenersLogsDB = DatabaseController.getInstance().getNotifyMeListenersLogsDB();
        notifyMeListenersLogsDB.writeNotifyMeListenersException(notifyMeListenersApplicationInitializationException);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Of course, I put the @SuppressWarnings to suppress it, but I'd like to know the cause. Anyone can help?

Comment: Recompile with `-Xlint:unchecked` for more detail.

Comment: Remove  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") that tells you which lines causing the issue.

Comment: Wow.. those are some long names! :)

Comment: I think it's that Class.forName line personally

Comment: [unchecked] unchecked call to getConstructor(Class<?>...) as a member of the raw type Class
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in class Class

Comment: [unchecked] unchecked call to getMethod(String,Class<?>...) as a member of the raw type Class       [unchecked] unchecked call to getMethod(String,Class<?>...) as a member of the raw type Class  [unchecked] unchecked cast
required: ArrayList<ChannelAccount>
found:    Object

Comment: I did put in the "-Xlint:unchecked" and got the details. So, now the question, so why doesn't solve the problem by catching a ClassCastException - I tried it does not work?

Comment: One of the reasons IDEs were created was to answer those types of questions automatically.

Comment: IMHO shorter variable names would be easier to read.

Comment: Does it help if you replace `Class` with `Class<?>`?

Comment: Yes, I put in Class<?> and it helped. However, this is still causing a problem:         channelAccounts = (ArrayList<ChannelAccount>) channelAccountStringsParserImplementedParseMethod.invoke(channelAccountStringsParserImplementedInstance, responseContent);
[unchecked] unchecked cast
required: ArrayList<ChannelAccount>
found:    Object

Comment: Never mind unchecked or unsafe operations, it's the verbose and repetitive operations you need to worry about ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class is a parameterized class.  you should use `Class<?>` (or something more specific if necessary).  of course, the compiler error probably tells you exactly where the problem is.

Also, this line is an unchecked cast, but you have no choice on that one:

```
channelAccounts = (ArrayList<ChannelAccount>)channelAccountStringsParserImplementedParseMethod.invoke(channelAccountStringsParserImplementedInstance, responseContent);
```

Comment: You mean no solution this this, and I have to live with the @SuppressWarning?

Comment: @ikevinjp - for the result of the `invoke()` call, yes, you cannot solve that in java without an unchecked cast (reflection does not play nicely with generics).